# ArrayList methods are not working

Tags: java, arraylist

I am learning about Java and I'm stuck with this `ArrayList` problem: the compiler give me error when I try to use simple methods, like `add`. Here is the code:

```
public class ArrayList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        list.add("Value A");
        list.add("Value B");
        list.add("Value C");
    }
}
```

The method is defined in [the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29).

It should be really simple to do it, but I really don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: You need to provide the error you are receiving. Think if someone walked up to you and said "the compiler give me error when I try to use simple methods, like add" what would be your first question....What is the error?...

Comment: By the way, use generics.  The `list` variable should be defined as an `List<String>` and initialized as an `new ArrayList<String>()`, or a `new ArrayList<>()` in Java 7.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have created your own `ArrayList` class and aren't using the [built-in Java class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).  You haven't defined `add`.

Comment: @Downvoter: Why the downvote?  My analysis of the problem is correct.

Comment: I almost fell in the trap (raw type).

Comment: I don't know why I got notification for this comment. I didn't downvote, I want to DOUBLE upvote. I love your answer.

Comment: @nickecarlo I don't know; I just know it's currently +16 / -1.

Answer (score 5):

Change your code to

```
java.util.ArrayList list = new java.util.ArrayList();
```

This will tell the compiler that you want the predefined ArrayList, not your newly defined ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple. Just change your class name `ArrayList` to something else, because `ArrayList` is a default class in Java.

Comment: What do you mean by "default class"?

Comment: I mean predefined class in java

Answer (score -1):

ublic class ArrayList {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    list.add("Value A");
    list.add("Value B");
    list.add("Value C");
}
```

}

your className is ArrayList   try to change the name and import ArrayList Class package

Answer (score -2):

Why are you creating a new class called ArrayList? Surely you want to do something like:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("Value A");
list.add("Value B");
list.add("Value C");
```

?

Answer (score -2):

ArrayLists have to be initialized differently to standard arrays.

What you want is something like this:

```
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
list.add(Object o);
```

Remember that nearly everything in Java is an `Object`.

So you can do:

```
ArrayList<String>...
ArrayList<Integer>...
```

But the most powerful feature of ArrayLists, and the reason I use them, is when you start making your own classes - for instance, in game development, a common class people make is a Sprite -- you could create an ArrayList of all sprites, such as below:

```
public class Sprite {}....
ArrayList<Sprite> spriteList = new ArrayList<Sprite>();
```

Comment: -1. Not only does this answer not correctly address, the problem, it proposes `ArrayList<Int>`, which is invalid in standard Java.

Comment: @WChargin - Changed to Integer as an object, instead of as an int. Sorry about the mistake. -_-