# not generic Error in Java HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I am getting the below error for HashMap in the Java code.

**Error** - "*The type HashMap is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <>*"

```
package com.example.map;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class HashMap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // compilation error here                vvvvvvv
        Map<Integer, String> mapHttpErrors = new HashMap<>();

        mapHttpErrors.put(200, "OK");
        mapHttpErrors.put(303, "See Other");
        mapHttpErrors.put(404, "Not Found");
        mapHttpErrors.put(500, "Internal Server Error");

        System.out.println(mapHttpErrors);      

    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like the same reason [this person failed when using `ArrayList`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491870/arraylist-methods-are-not-working) -- you named your class the same name as the type you're attempting to use.

Comment: change the name of your class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error is telling you, your `HashMap` class isn't generic, so your code makes no sense.

You should not make classes with the same names as built-in classes.

Comment: Thank you. I just tried changing the class name and got rid of this error.

Answer (score 2):

You have named your own class `HashMap` as well.

When you write `new HashMap` the compiler thinks you're referring to your own class which indeed does not specify any generic parameters.

You can (and in fact: should) either change the name of your class to something else or explicitly refer to `java.util.HashMap` in your code:

```
Map<Integer, String> mapHttpErrors = new java.util.HashMap<>();
```

Comment: To state the obvious, creating a class with the same name as a commonly used java.util class is highly confusing.  Changing the name of your class to be `HashMapTest` or `LocalHashMap` or ... would certainly be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

In the following line `HashMap` refers to the public class you created:

```
Map<Integer, String> mapHttpErrors = new **HashMap**<>();
```

Naming your class with exact the same name as classes from official Java API is often a very bad idea. But if you're sure that instead of that, you still want to keep the old name, here is the way you can use the `HashMap` from `java.util` package:

```
Map<Integer, String> mapHttpErrors = new java.util.HashMap<>();
```

But again, remember that naming your classes as you did in your program is rather a bad idea.

Comment: Instead of typing "Sorry this should be a comment" just delete the answer and write it as a comment...

Comment: I can't find this option in mobile app, and I just wanted to be quick to don't get tons of downvotes... Yeah they actually started...